# Plots generated in chunk don't appear with rmarkdown::render_site()

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating a website with

`Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render_site()"`

I am generating both html and pdf versions of documents. A plot generated in a chunk does not appear unless the pdf doc is generated before the html doc.

Here are the files:

**index.Rmd**

```
---
title: "My Website"
---

* [Test1 page](test1.html)

* [Test2 page](test2.html)
```

**_site.yml**

`name: "my-website"`

**test1.Rmd** (html generated first)

````
---
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) + geom_point()
```
````

**test2.Rmd** (pdf generated first)

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) + geom_point()
```
````

After running `render_site()` via `Rscript`, `test1.html` is blank --- there is no `test1_files` subdirectory. However, `test2.html` shows this plot (and of course `test2_files` exists):

[image]

This happens with both Rmarkdown 1.10 and 1.10.14, the development version as of October 31.

In a more complicated real life example, the plots don't appear even if I switch the document order, but I am hoping that the answer to this problem will help with the more complicated one.

UPDATE: In addition to the suggestions by @giocomai, a workaround is to compile test1.Rmd twice:

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render_site()"
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render_site('test1.Rmd')"
```

This seems to work even if you compile multiple single files. Presumably the clean-up is less aggressive in the single-file case.

Answer (score 2):

I could replicate your problem, and I think this is related to the fact that `rmarkdown::render()` cleans the files after it creates a pdf output, as it thinks those files are useless, and `render_site` copies the files to the `_site` folder only after all output types have been rendered.

In `rmarkdown::render()` there is an option to set `clean=FALSE`, but it does not seem to be available to `rmarkdown::render_site()`, as arguments are not passed to `render`.

I think it would be worth filing it as an issue to Rmarkdown, as it shouldn't be too difficult to pass over the argument.

As a workaround, you can force `cache = TRUE` in the chunks of the relevant Rmd document. So, for, example, the code chunk in your test1.Rmd would look like:

````
```{r, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, cache = TRUE}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) + geom_point()
```
````

notice the `cache = TRUE` in the chunk options. With the cache enabled, the folder is preserved and it is correctly copied to the `_site` folder.

You can also set `knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE)` for all chunks.

This solves your problem, but there should probably be more elegant solutions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this! Is there any reason the figure-html subdirectory ever needs to be cleaned?  The figures there are linked in the html files, it seems that removing that directory is a bug, no? Or am I missing something.

Comment: so, if one outputs a pdf file, then they probably don't want temp files to remain around... so i think the `clean = TRUE` is a sensible default. Also, if one uses `render_site`, the expectation is that they probably want (only) html files, not a pdf for each page. I guess this is why there's no built-in mechanism to deal with this combination.

Comment: Certainly figure-pdf should be removed. But I can't think of a use case (in the context of site-rendering) for figure-html to ever be cleaned, pdf or no. I think you're right that the focus was on html and the dual generation of pdf/html has unearthed some problems.

Comment: @RobertMcDonald FYI the issue has been fixed on Github: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown Thanks!